# Fetch data in a function

Tags: php, pdo

so i'm trying to fetch my data in a (PDO) function more than one place at my site, and don't want to echo the rows out in the function. can't seem to make it work.

my function

```
function getUser(){
global $db;
$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$sql = "SELECT firstName FROM users WHERE userId = $userId";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

//the problem
echo $row['firstName'];

}
```

How i call the function

```
<?php
    getUser();
?>
```

I don't wanna echo the $row['firstname'] out in the function, but on the sites where i wanna use it?

Hope it makes sensce?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of echo'ing it:

```
//the problem
echo $row['firstName'];
```

Just return it

```
return $row['firstName'];
```

Then when you call it you can do like this:

```
<?php
    $user = getUser();
    echo "$user<br />\n";
?>
```

If you need to return more than one column you do this:

```
return array($row['col1'], $row['col2']);
```

and then assign it on the other end like this:

```
list($col1, $col2) = getXyz($someID);
```

Comment: Hey again, and if i wanna return more values from the table like userId, title, image?

Comment: You can return an array and assign it with a `list(...) = getX();`